# An alternative to StringBuilders by just using Strings?

Tags: java, string

Currently I have this....

```
 public static String repeatLetters(int multiplier, String text)
{  
  StringBuilder repeat = new StringBuilder();

  for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
  {
     for (int j = 0; j < multiplier; j++)
     { 
        repeat.append(text.charAt(i));
     }
  }

  System.out.println("Letters Repeated:");
  System.out.println("-----------");
  System.out.println(repeat);
  System.out.println("--------------");

  return repeat.toString();
}
```

I would like to code in such a way that the last statement which currently reads "return repeat.toString();" to just "return value". How can I structure this code to do just that? Is there a way to do that without using StringBuilders and just using Strings?

Comment: you could use a String literal instead of StringBuilder and use + instead of append() in the loop... But that is not a good practice...

Comment: Sure, just concatenate the string with itself and the next text each time. `String value = ""; value += text.charAt(i);`

Comment: why do you wanto to do that?

Comment: The method you are using is the method which is good and used most widely. but still if you want to use it, try @TheLostMind's comment

Comment: What is the wrong with `repeat.toString()`?

Comment: I would always prefer to go with StringBuilder rather than String. It's more efficient in terms of performance and memory.

Comment: @ManojShrestha - Unless you use the same string many many times... :)

Comment: @TheLostMind: Since, we're dealing with a method, we have to assume that the multiplier can have large values too. So, as a good programmer, you should always keep that in mind.

Comment: @ManojShrestha - Ya. here StringBuilder is the obvious choice... I just wanted to say if the OP wants to use a string several times, he might as well go for a String literal rather than a StringBuilder..

Comment: You can get rid of the `toString()` call by just changing the return type to `CharSequence`. I always use `CharSequence` where possible as you can do a lot of things you normally do with `String` with a `CharSequence` as well and have the freedom to use `String`, `StringBuilder`, `CharBuffer`, etc. at all places. And if you really need a `String` somewhere you can still invoke `toString()` on the `CharSequence` at that place.

Answer (score 2):

In your special case you can simplify your code. But in most cases, using `StringBuilder` is the better choice. And “using `String` directly” is not a choice at all.

```
public static String repeatLetters(int multiplier, String text) {
    final int numChars=text.length();
    char[] data=new char[numChars*multiplier];
    for(int i=0, j=0, k=multiplier; i<numChars; i++, j=k, k+=multiplier)
        Arrays.fill(data, j, k, text.charAt(i));
    return new String(data);
}
```

Comment: +1, nice hack. I don't think you necessarily need all those iterators however - `j` & `k` can be merged into one.

Comment: @Boris the Spider: I decided against merging them as it would imply either, performing `+multiplier` more than necessary or to use a less readable syntax (`+=` inside the loop body).

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8:

```
public static String repeatChars(final String in, int numTimes) {
    return IntStream.range(0, in.length()).
            mapToObj(Integer::valueOf).
            flatMap((index) -> IntStream.range(0, numTimes).mapToObj((rep) -> String.valueOf(in.charAt(index)))).collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

This essentially does the same thing. It also *uses* a `StringBuilder` under the hood, so should be only a little less efficient than using one explicitly - it has to create quite a few `String` objects in the process but the same `String` (in the repeat) should be shared across the iterations.

Essentially we take an `IntStream` of the range `[0, in.length)` and for each `int` we convert it to an `Integer` then `flatMap` a new `IntStream` of the range `[0, numTimes)` which we map each `int` of to `String.valueOf(in.charAt(index))`; i.e. we repeat the character at the current point in the first `Stream` for each element in the second. We then collect the `Stream` into a `String` using `Collectors.joining()`.

Answer (score -1):

Unefficient but

```
public static String repeatLetters(int multiplier, String text)
{  
  String repeat = new String();

  for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
  {
     for (int j = 0; j < multiplier; j++)
     { 
        repeat+=text.charAt(i);
        //Or maybe repeat+=new String(text.charAt(i));
     }
  }

  System.out.println("Letters Repeated:");
  System.out.println("-----------");
  System.out.println(repeat);
  System.out.println("--------------");

  return repeat;
}
```

Every time you assign a string, you actually assign a new object and send the old to garbage collection

Comment: And create a `new StringBuilder` which will also need to be GC'd.

Comment: @BoristheSpider when you instantiate a new StringBuilder, you instantiate one object that grows. Every time you do a+=b, you instantiate b and then instantiate a new a. B and the old a get garbaged. The StringBuilder won't until method ends

Comment: Not quite. `a += b` is _actually_ `a = new StringBuilder(a).append(b).toString()` when it's compiled; remember that `String`s are immutable. This is the extra `StringBuilder` i meant. And remember - it is created for _each_ iteration.